# DataGrip Визуализация связей между таблицами

Tags: jetbrains, datagrip

В DataGrip есть возможность визуализировать базу данных. При визуализации, связи отображаются, но идут от таблицы к таблице:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом можно это пофиксить, и сделать так, чтобы отображение было от ключа к ключу, как это реализовано, например, тут:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В DataGrip так сделать пока нельзя.

Завёл тикет: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-13144

Comment: Занятный факт: скриншот более наглядной и удобной визуализации сделан в DbVisualizer. Как и в JetBrains DataGrip, для визуализации в DbVisualizer используется yFiles.